# Find the name of motherboard and make of hard drive using visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to create a program to gather information about users pcs. So far I have been able to gather thigns like the os, processor, hard drive size and graphics information and I was just wondering how I would be able to collect the name of the motherboard they are using (or model) and the make of the hard drives in their machines. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The whole point is for an application. What good is it telling people to pop off the lid when they may not understand it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to look into what is available with WMI. Bear in mind that all of the information you want might not be available. You can try `Win32_BaseBoard` for your Motherboard information.

Example code from the Creator for Disk Drive Model information:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace WMISample

    Public Class MyWMIQuery

        Public Overloads Shared Function Main() As Integer

            Try
                Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( "root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive") 

                For Each queryObj As ManagementObject in searcher.Get()

                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------")
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_DiskDrive instance")
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------")
                    Console.WriteLine("Model: {0}", queryObj("Model"))
                Next
            Catch err As ManagementException
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
            End Try
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```