# How to get Motherboard name in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, motherboard

My program needs an upgrade and I was looking for the Motherboard name and Maker(Developer).

And here's the problem there is WMI what is offered almost everywhere, and it lines up with
Console.Writeline, what i want to do is to get the Label to show the same thing what i get with WMI.

The solution what was offered by Thorster Dittmar, did not work, I tried that at the beginning:

> Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11164991

Comment: @draks... I think the question is not how to get the Motherboard name, but how to display it in a `Label` instead of outputting it to the console.

Comment: Please try to put some effort into editing your question so that it's readable and not just walls of text. Use **bold** and *italics* *sparingly*.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to understand your question, but what I read from it is:

You want to display information you get via WMI in a `Label`, but the output so far is on the `Console`?

Well, use the following steps:

1. Create a Windows Forms application
2. Place `Label` on form
3. Copy code that accesses WMI to `Form_Load` event handler
4. Instead of `Console.WriteLine(xyz)` do `label1.Text = xyz`

That should be it. If that doesn't answer your question, please edit your question so it becomes clearer what you want.

Comment: Yes, well, what's your question about that? The error says it all. You're trying to access an instance member of a class without actually specifying an object instance. Could be you've copied a `shared` method into your source code that is now trying to access an instance member. Can't tell you anymore, because you didn't show any relevant source code. If you did you'd have good chances of your problem getting solved.